# Listening for window resize event to close responsive (Sidr) menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

In this project: http://www.bureauforgood.com/ia-runningstrong/1.1-Home.html

I'm using a jQuery plugin named Sidr (http://www.berriart.com/sidr/) to create a menu that sliders in from the right on the responsive/mobile version. The breakpoint is 767px.

Th issue is, once you make the window narrow and open the sidr menu, the plugin currently doesn't hide the menu back when you make the window wider. I know I'm supposed to add an event listener to listen for window resize, but I don't know how (I don't know JS very well).

Menu code is

```
<div id="sidr-right">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Life in Indian Communities</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">What We Do</a></li>               
      <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>             
      <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>             
      <li><a href="#">News & Press</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <form>
      <input class="six right" placeholder="Search" name="search" type="search" />
  </form>
```

Sidr code is

```
    /*! Sidr - v1.1.1 - 2013-03-14
 * https://github.com/artberri/sidr
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Alberto Varela; Licensed MIT */
(function(e){var t=!1,i=!1,o={isUrl:function(e){var t=RegExp("^(https?:\\/\\/)?((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$","i");return t.test(e)?!0:!1},loadContent:function(e,t){e.html(t)},addPrefix:function(e){var t=e.attr("id"),i=e.attr("class");"string"==typeof t&&""!==t&&e.attr("id",t.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+)/g,"sidr-id-$1")),"string"==typeof i&&""!==i&&"sidr-inner"!==i&&e.attr("class",i.replace(/([A-Za-z0-9_.\-]+)/g,"sidr-class-$1")),e.removeAttr("style")},execute:function(o,n,s){"function"==typeof n?(s=n,n="sidr"):n||(n="sidr");var a,d,l,c=e("#"+n),f=e(c.data("body")),u=e("html"),p=c.outerWidth(!0),y=c.data("speed"),v=c.data("side");if("open"===o||"toogle"===o&&!c.is(":visible")){if(c.is(":visible")||t)return;if(i!==!1)return r.close(i,function(){r.open(n)}),void 0;t=!0,"left"===v?(a={left:p+"px"},d={left:"0px"}):(a={right:p+"px"},d={right:"0px"}),l=u.scrollTop(),u.css("overflow-x","hidden").scrollTop(l),f.css({width:f.width(),position:"absolute"}).animate(a,y),c.css("display","block").animate(d,y,function(){t=!1,i=n,"function"==typeof s&&s(n)})}else{if(!c.is(":visible")||t)return;t=!0,"left"===v?(a={left:0},d={left:"-"+p+"px"}):(a={right:0},d={right:"-"+p+"px"}),l=u.scrollTop(),u.removeAttr("style").scrollTop(l),f.animate(a,y),c.animate(d,y,function(){c.removeAttr("style"),f.removeAttr("style"),e("html").removeAttr("style"),t=!1,i=!1,"function"==typeof s&&s(n)})}}},r={open:function(e,t){o.execute("open",e,t)},close:function(e,t){o.execute("close",e,t)},toogle:function(e,t){o.execute("toogle",e,t)}};e.sidr=function(t){return r[t]?r[t].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1)):"function"!=typeof t&&"string"!=typeof t&&t?(e.error("Method "+t+" does not exist on jQuery.sidr"),void 0):r.toogle.apply(this,arguments)},e.fn.sidr=function(t){var i=e.extend({name:"sidr",speed:200,side:"left",source:null,renaming:!0,body:"body"},t),n=i.name,s=e("#"+n);if(0===s.length&&(s=e("<div />").attr("id",n).appendTo(e("body"))),s.addClass("sidr").addClass(i.side).data({speed:i.speed,side:i.side,body:i.body}),"function"==typeof i.source){var a=i.source(n);o.loadContent(s,a)}else if("string"==typeof i.source&&o.isUrl(i.source))e.get(i.source,function(e){o.loadContent(s,e)});else if("string"==typeof i.source){var d="",l=i.source.split(",");if(e.each(l,function(t,i){d+='<div class="sidr-inner">'+e(i).html()+"</div>"}),i.renaming){var c=e("<div />").html(d);c.find("*").each(function(t,i){var r=e(i);o.addPrefix(r)}),d=c.html()}o.loadContent(s,d)}else null!==i.source&&e.error("Invalid Sidr Source");return this.each(function(){var t=e(this),i=t.data("sidr");i||(t.data("sidr",n),t.click(function(e){e.preventDefault(),r.toogle(n)}))})}})(jQuery);
```

What code would I add, and where--in the .js file or on the html?

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. Insert this code in your own .js file. You can set a custom breakpoint

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($('body').hasClass('sidr-open') && $(window).width() >= 768) {
    //call here your closing function
  }
});
```

Comment: I tested on Chrome and IE10 when I minimize the browser window the mobile menu icon is shown. When I click on the mobile menu icon to expand the Sidr menu and then just press the Restore button on the browser (which maximizes the browser to full screen), the Sidr menu is still displayed and my page still stays small... Any idea why that happens?